# What is the C++ convention when I need to add a useless return statement?

Tags: c++

I was trying to write a function that returns the first non-repeated character in a string. The algorithm I made was:

- Assert that the string is non-empty
- Iterate through the string and add all non-repeated characters to a set
- Assert that the set be non-empty
- Iterate through string again and return the first character that's in the set
- Add a useless return statement to make the compiler happy. (Arbitrarily return 'F')

Obviously my algorithm is very "brute force" and could be improved on. It runs, anyhow. I was wondering if there's a better way to do this and was also wondering what the convention is for useless return statements. Don't be afraid to criticize me harshly. I'm trying to become a C++ stiffler. ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

char first_nonrepeating_char(const std::string&);


int main() {

    std::string S = "yodawgIheardyoulike";

    std::cout << first_nonrepeating_char(S);


}

// Finds that first non-repeated character in the string
char first_nonrepeating_char(const std::string& str) {
    assert (str.size() > 0);
    std::set<char> nonRepChars; 
    std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin();
    while (it != str.end()) { 
        if (nonRepChars.count(*it) == 0) { 
            nonRepChars.insert(*it);
        } else { 
            nonRepChars.erase(*it);
        }
        ++it;
    }
    assert (nonRepChars.size() != 0);
    it = str.begin();
    while (it != str.end()) {
        if (nonRepChars.count(*it) == 1) return (*it);
        ++it;
    }
    return ('F'); // NEVER HAPPENS
}
```

Comment: There's `[[noreturn]]` for specific situations.

Comment: If a sentence such as the last return cannot be reached some people like an `assert(false);` instead of the comment.

Comment: @chris: `[[noreturn]]` is indeed part of one possible solution, but (1) it can't be used directly here, and (2) it's not supported by Visual C++, thus it's a bit impractical.

Comment: What if the string in question is `"aa"`? You might reconsider your "useless" return statement, and return `EOF` as an `int`, or another invalid character value.

Comment: I sometimes use `assert (!"whatever terse error message")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is just getting rid of warnings.

Ideally you should be able to just say

```
assert( false );  // Should never get here
```

but unfortunately that does *not* get rid of all warnings with the compilers I use most, namely Visual C++ and g++.

Instead I do this:

```
xassert_should_never_get_here();
```

where `xassert_should_never_get_here` is a function that

- is declared as "noreturn" by compiler-specific means, e.g. `__declspec` for Visual C++,
- has an `assert(false)` to handle debug builds,
- then throws a `std::logic_error`.

The last two points are accomplished by a macro `XASSERT` (its actual name in my code is `CPPX_XASSERT`, it's always a good idea to use prefixes for macro names so as to reduce name conflict probability).

---

Of course, the assertion that you should not get to the end, is equivalent to an assertion that the argument string does contain at least one non-repeated character, which therefore is a **precondition** of the function (part of its contract), which I think should be documented by a comment. :-)

There are three main "modern C++" ways of coding things up when you do not have that precondition, namely

- choose one `char` value to signify "no such", e.g. `'\0'`, or
- throw an exception in the case of no such, or
- return a boxed result which can be logically "empty", e.g. [the Boost class corresponding to Barton and Nackmann's `Fallible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917769/how-to-use-boostoptionalt-to-return-null-in-c).

---

About the algorithm: when you're not intested in *where* the first non-repeating `char` is, you can avoid the rescan of the string by maintaining a count per character, e.g. by using a `map<char, int>` instead of a `set<char>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler and "cleaner" way of doing it, but it is not computationally faster than "brute force".

Use a table that counts the number of occurrences of each character in the input string.

Then go over the input string one more time, and return the first character whose count is 1.

```
char GetFirstNonRepeatedChar(const char* s)
{
    int table[256] = {0};
    for (int i=0; s[i]!=0; i++)
        table[s[i]]++;
    for (int i=0; s[i]!=0; i++)
        if (table[s[i]] == 1)
            return s[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Note: the above will work for ASCII strings.

If you're using a different format, then you'll need to change the `256` (and the `char` of course).